# How to wrap a text with shortcode into php file?

Tags: php, shortcode

I want to wrap a text with shortcode into the `single.php` file.

- The shortcode is: `[box type="note" align="aligncenter" ][/box]` and
- the code is:

  ```
  Διοργανωτής διαγωνισμού: <?php the_field('diorganwths_diagwnismou');?></br>
  Απαιτεί λογαριασμό Facebook: <?php the_field('apaitei_logariasmo_facebook');?></br>
  ```

How can i wrap the this php code so i can have it into the box as the shortcode orders?

Comment: If you show us all the code in single.php (by editing your question), we may be able to show you where the solution code can go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`load_value`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/filters/acfload_value/) ACF filter:

```
function wpse0605_acf_load_field( $field ) {
    $field = '[box]' . $field . '[/box]';
    return $field;
}

// acf/load_field/name={$field_name} - filter for a specific field based on its name
add_filter('acf/load_value/name=diorganwths_diagwnismou', 'wpse0605_acf_load_field');
add_filter('acf/load_value/name=apaitei_logariasmo_facebook', 'wpse0605_acf_load_field');
```

The code can go into the theme's `functions.php`, or inside a plugin constructor.

Comment: @daldaeb, i tried it but it didn't work. Can you explain me more where do i have to insert the code because i want to use it in the `single.php` and not in the `functions.php`

Comment: @Charitos it seems you don't understand filters very well. [Have a read of this](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-beginners-guide-to-wordpress-actions-and-filters/). The Codex links at the end of article are also useful.